# Select records that are present on one date but not on another?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If I have a table t1 that looks this where records are unique on a combination of item, size and date;

```
item    size    date
1234    S   2013-02-11
1234    M   2013-02-11
1234    L   2013-02-11
9999    S   2013-02-11
9999    M   2013-02-11
9999    L   2013-02-11
1234    S   2013-02-13
1234    M   2013-02-13
1234    L   2013-02-13
9999    S   2013-02-13
9999    M   2013-02-13
```

How can I retrieve the item and size that is missing from 2013-02-13 when compared to 2013-02-11?

The return I am looking for is,

```
item    size
9999    L
```

I have tried;

```
SELECT ta.item, 
         ta.size
FROM t1 ta 
    LEFT JOIN t1 tb 
        ON ta.item = tb.item
            AND ta.size = tb.size
WHERE ta.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND tb.date = '2013-02-13'
   AND tb.size IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT item, size 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT item, size 
                    FROM t1
                    WHERE t1.date = '2013-02-13'
                  )
```

both return empty sets.

The only way I have managed to get this to work is by using temporary tables;

```
CREATE temporary table temp1
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE date = '2013-02-11';

CREATE temporary table temp2
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE date = '2013-02-13';

SELECT temp1.item, temp1.size FROM temp1
   LEFT JOIN temp2 
        ON temp1.item = temp2.item AND temp1.size = temp2.size
WHERE temp2.size IS NULL
```

Temporary tables are not going to be possible. How can I achieve this without using temp tables?

Many thanks,

(please be gentle, i am just starting out!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggregation query:

```
select item, size
from t1
group by item, size
having sum(case when date = '2013-02-11' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       sum(case when date = '2013-02-13' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This is an example of a "groups within groups" query.  By varying the `having` clause, you have a lot of flexibility in the conditions you want to meet.  For instance:

```
having sum(case when date = '2013-02-11' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when date = '2013-02-13' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

would return combinations that are present in the data, but missing on either day.

Comment: +1, although if you limit the rows before the grouping to those `where date in ('2013-02-11', '2013-02-13')`, you can simplify the `having`conditions in both cases.

Comment: @AndriyM . . . Yes, that is a good idea for this particular question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works a charm although I have to admit I don't quite understand how- I will study this as the extra flexibility could be very useful

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT  item, size
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   date = '2013-02-11'
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  item, size
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   date = '2013-02-13'
        ) b ON  a.item = b.item AND
                a.size = b.size
WHERE b.size IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d726/9)

Comment: I up-voted you but there is no need for the subquery. Put the 2/13 in the ON; and the 2/11 in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this simple query

```
SELECT item, size FROM dbo.Table_1 WHERE date = '2013-02-11'
EXCEPT
SELECT item, size FROM dbo.Table_1 WHERE date = '2013-02-13'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support `INTERSECT and EXCEPT` operators.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I should have stated I was using mySQL, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided valid solutions for you, and this post merely addresses your failed attempts, explaining what was missing and how it could be fixed.

This query

```
SELECT ta.item, 
         ta.size
FROM t1 ta 
    LEFT JOIN t1 tb 
        ON ta.item = tb.item
            AND ta.size = tb.size
WHERE ta.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND tb.date = '2013-02-13'
   AND tb.size IS NULL
```

fails because there's a contradiction in the WHERE clause. The query is trying to find a row where `tb.size` is NULL, which would mean that the `tb` instance didn't have a match with the `ta` one, *and* `tb.date` is a particular value. Now, if there's no match in `tb`, all its columns will be returned as NULLs, which includes `tb.date`, meaning it cannot be equal to a value and be null at the same time.

Obviously, your intention was different. You wanted to left-join one subset of a table to another subset (of the same table, as it happens). In that case, the condition defining the subset you are joining should be put into the ON clause. That is, you are not joining on the sole condition that both `item` and `size` columns of both instances match, but on the combined condition of those columns matching *and* the other instance's `date` being a particular value. So, this is what you should have instead:

```
SELECT ta.item, 
         ta.size
FROM t1 ta 
    LEFT JOIN t1 tb 
        ON ta.item = tb.item
            AND ta.size = tb.size
            AND tb.date = '2013-02-13'
WHERE ta.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND tb.date = '2013-02-13'
   AND tb.size IS NULL
```

The other query

```
SELECT item, size 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT item, size 
                    FROM t1
                    WHERE t1.date = '2013-02-13'
                  )
```

seems to be a result of confusing `EXISTS` with `IN`.

First, how EXISTS works. It returns `true` when its subquery returns a non-empty row set. It doesn't matter which columns, only the presence of rows counts. If none is returned, the result is `false`. This way, your query reads like this:

> Return every row whose `date` is `'2013-02-11'` AND there aren't *any* rows for `date = '2013-02-11'`.

While you probably meant to say by that query something like this:

> Return every row whose `date` is `'2013-02-11'` AND there are no *corresponding* row with the *same* `item` and `size` and with the `date` of `'2013-02-11'`.

That is, you need to *correlate* the EXISTS subquery with the main query, which means including the current row's `size` and `item` into the EXISTS test. So, this is what the fix might look like:

```
SELECT item, size 
FROM t1 ta
WHERE ta.date = '2013-02-11'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT item, size 
                    FROM t1 tb
                    WHERE tb.date = '2013-02-13'
                      AND ta.item = tb.item
                      AND ta.size = tb.size
                  )
```

On the other hand, you could rewrite the same query to use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`. Here:

```
SELECT item, size 
FROM t1
WHERE date = '2013-02-11'
   AND (item, size) NOT IN (
                            SELECT item, size 
                            FROM t1
                            WHERE date = '2013-02-13'
                           )
```

which basically says:

> Return every row whose `(item, size)` pair for `date = '2013-02-11'` is not in the `(item, size)` pair set for `date = '2013-02-11'`.

An `IN`/`NOT IN` query may often look clearer than its `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` counterpart. Whether the two would result in identical query plans is another matter, and you should probably test before deciding which method to use (but that applies to the `LEFT JOIN + WHERE IS NULL` method too, of course).

Comment: Thanks for this Andriy. I had hoped someone would explain where I went wrong. Your post is really appreciated.